# When I try to retrieve the Attachment by ID, I get an ErrorItemNotFound response

Tags: outlook, python-requests, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

My problem seems to be to a permission error.  When I try to retrieve the Attachment by ID using an EWS Soap request, I get an ErrorItemNotFound response.

So I'm roughly following the GetAttachment Example from Microsoft -- http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item

My WebService that receives the EWS Token, EWS URL, and Attachment ID is written in Python.

Here is what I have working.

I have an Outlook AddIn written in Javascript that responds to mail item selections.

I retrieve an EWS Token using the isRest=false option and

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(getEWSCallback,
options);
```

For mail that has an attachment, I extract information about the attachment including the attachment Id.

Here is a sample of the attachment information:

```
{

"id": 
"XZkADdlMDAxOTFiLWZmMWYtNGI1Ni1iYmM2LTlhOTJjYTBmMTI1MQBGAAAAAAAO1b910PexQpLkqgde51DABwAyR2+p4hG4RbXOV7pJuYtiAAAAAAEMAAAyR2+p4hG4RbXOV7pJuYtiAABsXaGoAAABEgAQAJ8Lans/ZeZLrkpk6mQ/QQg=",

"name": 
"xxxxxxxxxxx.docx",

"contentType": 
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",

"size": 
162008,

"attachmentType": 
0,

"isInline": 
false

}
```

I pass the EWS Token, EWS Url, and Attachment information to my webservice; which is written in Python.

My WebService constructs the soap request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">

<soap:Header>

<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />

</soap:Header>

  <soap:Body>

    <GetAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"

    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">

      <AttachmentShape/>

      <AttachmentIds>

        <t:AttachmentId Id="XZkADdlMDAxOTFiLWZmMWYtNGI1Ni1iYmM2LTlhOTJjYTBmMTI1MQBGAAAAAAAO1b910PexQpLkqgde51DABwAyR2+p4hG4RbXOV7pJuYtiAAAAAAEMAAAyR2+p4hG4RbXOV7pJuYtiAABsXaGoAAABEgAQAJ8Lans/ZeZLrkpk6mQ/QQg="/>

      </AttachmentIds>

    </GetAttachment>

  </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I then send a Webrequest with python:

```
authHeaders = {

'Authorization': 
"Bearer " + ewsToken,

'Content-type': 
'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

}


webResp = requests.post(url=ewsUrl, headers=authHeaders, data=requestString)
```

The response I get is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<s:Header>

<h:ServerVersionInfo
MajorVersion="15"
MinorVersion="20"
MajorBuildNumber="2430"
MinorBuildNumber="27"
Version="V2018_01_08"

xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

</s:Header>

<s:Body>

<m:GetAttachmentResponse
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">

<m:ResponseMessages>

<m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage
ResponseClass="Error">

<m:MessageText>The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.</m:MessageText>

<m:ResponseCode>ErrorItemNotFound</m:ResponseCode>

<m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>

<m:Attachments/>

</m:GetAttachmentResponseMessage>

</m:ResponseMessages>

</m:GetAttachmentResponse>

</s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
```

My understanding is that the ErrorItemNotFound response indicates either (1) The item doesn't exists or (2) I don't have permission to access it.

If I use a corrupt EWS Token, I get a Http 401 error that indicates I'm not authorized to make the EWS Post.  So I believe the Bearer authentication is working correctly.

Any thoughts or help?